# Создание карты. Установка маркера и получение координат

Tags: google-maps-api

Доброго времени суток. Хочу создать карту, при клике на которую появится маркер и координаты запишутся в форму. Сейчас карта есть, создание маркера кое-какое нашел, но оно каждый раз при клике создает новый маркер.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        draggable:true
    });
}
```

Что-то похожее, что мне нужно, есть на сайте http://www.mapcoordinates.net/ru. Главное, чтобы при клике по карте создавался маркер, а если кликнем в другое место, то этот же маркер перемещался туда.

Comment: С координатами разобрался.
        var lat = location.lat();
        var lng = location.lng();
где location - это position при создании маркера

Answer (score 1):

А все нашел решение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684274/googlemaps-v3-api-create-only-1-marker-on-click):

```
    var marker;

function placeMarker(location) {
  if ( marker ) {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  } else {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```